# Properties of vector multiplication: why is $(a^Tb)b = (bb^T)a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Why is it the case that $(a^Tb)b = (bb^T)a$?

I know that $a^Tb = b^Ta$, but I'm not sure why the above holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^Tb$ is a scalar. We have
$$
(a^Tb)b = b(a^Tb) = b(b^Ta) = (bb^T)a.
$$